# Socket IO not getting connected to server using swift

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, swift2, xcode7.1

I've downloaded a sample socket project from github https://github.com/appcoda/SocketIOChat

I'm using EICapitan and I've installed node js and I've also setup the IP in the sample  `var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.2:3000")!)`
When I run `node index.js` command on terminal it shows `Listening on *:3000` But when I run the sample app enter a name to connect user I dont receive any message like user connected. Is there something that I'm missing, I'm a beginner to node.js and socket.io. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what `index.js` file contains?

Comment: Its the same file mentioned in the above link in the srv-SocketChat.zip, no changes were made to it.

Comment: Use `127.0.0.1:3000` instead  `192.168.1.2:3000`

Comment: Wow, that seems to be working, according to the guidelines I thought we had to put our IP address, isn't it?

Comment: @Garelegend in general we should put IP address. Since you are using localhost there is no need to place IP address in it but when your app would be located at remote server you should use ip address of that server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are trying connect to incorrect ip address. 
Get your `inet` ip from `ifconfig` and place it to `SocketIOClient`. I would recommend you to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for development instead of `inet` address